# Radio in Bootstrap dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I need help with dropdown. I have radio in there but after choose that dropdown is closed and I must open it and click at other option again.

Or existing better solution?

in my case are invoices and I choosing from two types in last 2 months, actual month, year 2014 etc.
[image]

Comment: Please use the tag "twitter-bootstrap" instead of "bootstrap", Bootstrap is actually a program that runs for an OS, not the twitter made "bootstrap" for css. I'll edit for you this time, but please don't next time.

Answer (score -1):

You need to **prevent default** in JS to stop Twitter-Bootstrap from closing it using JS.

```
$(function(){
    $('.dropdown :radio').bind({
        click: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
})
```